# Google map : Specific building styling

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a google map, i use the Google Map Platform style creator to hide default place icon, display the building as flat. It works well. Now i am trying to changing style of a specific building (for example change color of the building i am curently in)

My code is working to display the map according to the style defined on Google Map Platform, i use geocoding to get the building id of the place i am.

```
const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

let currentPosition = {lat:50.63584018637185, lng:3.070463549079457}

let map;
async function initMap() {

  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),
    {
      zoom: 20,
      center: currentPosition,
      mapId: '<MY_MAP_ID>',
    }
  );

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: currentPosition,
    map: map,
  });

  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  const latLng = { lat: 37.42, lng: -122.08 };
  
  geocoder.geocode({ location: currentPosition }, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      const buildingId = results[0].place_id;

    } else {
      // Handle the error.
    }
  });
```

For styling a specific building i search in the documentation and found nothing, but when asking Bard (why not it's a google tool it should know the doc ^^) and it answser me :

```
// Create a JavaScript object to store the JSON file.
const myStyle = {
  "name": "My Custom Style",
  "description": "This is my custom style for Google Maps.",
  "version": 1,
  "rules": [
    {
      "selector": "path[id='my-building-id']",
      "stylers": [
        {
          "color": "#FF0000"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// Load the JSON file into the map.
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: { lat: 37.42, lng: -122.08 },
  zoom: 12,
});

map.loadStyle(myStyle);
```

But it don't work, the loadStyle method is undefined. Bard is sure of his answer but it's weird i found nothing on the web about that (Maybe a not yet implemented feature ?)

Maybe someone have information about this feature ? Any help will be welcome

Comment: `Bard is sure of his answer but it's weird i found nothing on the web about that ` I guess that's what you call hallucination. :'> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination_(artificial_intelligence)

Comment: @Yrll Thks for the link, it quite fun to see this behaviour, maybe less when it make you hope that the answer of your problem exist. Btw like MrUpsidedown try to say without any aggressiveness (i hope ^^) , those AI is not meant to code in place to code for us, it can help us but nothing more. We have still work , it will not (yet) replace us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to discussion with some developper that know very well this feature is not yet present. He think it was **maybe present** by the past for others project like dead Google map gaming service. But the answer for the moment is not possible with the google data.

But there is some other datasources for building footprints :

- [GlobalMLBuildingFootprints](https://github.com/microsoft/GlobalMLBuildingFootprints) (covering Europe)
- [Open Building](https://sites.research.google/open-buildings/) (not covering Europe at the moment)

I will use the GlobalMLBuildingFootprints dataset.

Even if it seems a good solution, this dataset have been made by AI on satelite data, footprint can in some case not matching the google map footprint. It will be for me an help to build my footprint, it will start from the dataset and edit the path to really match the google map footprint.

It's not a perfect solution but for the moment it's the only one i found.